# React memory leak, componentDidUnmount not working

Tags: reactjs, memory, fetch

I have reviewed many posts attempting to resolve this issue and have tried numerous ways to take care of this error, but the answer stills eludes me.  It is a common problem, I know, but my understanding of React appears to be inadequate to achieve resolution.  I'm trying to eliminate this error:

Can't perform a React state update on an unmounted component. This is a no-op, but it indicates a memory leak in your application. To fix, cancel all subscriptions and asynchronous tasks in the **componentWillUnmount** method.

I am unable to understand why **componentWillUnmount** does not resolve it.  Here is the code:

```
import React from 'react';
import ReactDOM from 'react-dom';

export class PracticeData extends React.Component{
  constructor(props){
    super(props);
    this.state = {
      data: [],
      isLoaded: false,
    }
}
componentDidMount() {
  this.mounted=true;
  fetch('https://jsonplaceholder.typicode.com/users')
  .then(res => res.json())
  .then(json => {
    this.setState({   //triggers a rendering cycle
      isLoaded: true,
      data: json,
    })
  });
} 
componentWillUnmount(){
  this.isLoaded=false;
}
  render(){
    var { isLoaded, data } = this.state;
      if(!isLoaded) {
        return <div>Loading...</div>
      } else {
       return (
         <div className="container-fluid">
           <div className="row">{
             data.map(data => <div key={data.id}>
               <div className="list">
                 <li className="header">{data.name}</li>
               <div className="body">  
                 <li><strong>Company:</strong> {data.company.name}</li>
                 <li><strong>User Name: </strong> {data.username}</li>
                 <li><strong>Email: </strong> {data.email}</li>
                 <li><strong>Phone: </strong>{data.phone}</li>
               </div>
                 <li className="address"><strong>Address: </strong></li>
               <div className="body">
                 <li><strong>Street:</strong> {data.address.street}</li>
                 <li><strong>Suite: </strong> {data.address.suite}</li>
                 <li><strong>City: </strong> {data.address.city}<br/></li>
                 <li><strong>Zip Code:</strong> {data.address.zipcode}</li>
               </div>   
               </div>
               </div>
              )}
           </div>
          </div>
        );
      }
    }
  }
ReactDOM.render(<PracticeData/>, document.getElementById('root'));
```

Answer (score 2):

The fetch looks like the only thing that can possibly resolve after a component unmounts, and for this you'll need an [AbortController](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/AbortController).

Basic usage is

```
const controller = new AbortController();
const { signal } = controller;

fetch(url, { signal })
```

Later if needed, you can abort the fetch

```
controller.abort()
```

Update to your component

```
export class PracticeData extends React.Component{
  constructor(props){
    super(props);
    this.state = {
      data: [],
      isLoaded: false,
    }
  }

  controller = new AbortController();

  componentDidMount() {
    this.mounted=true;
    const { signal } = this.controller;

    fetch('https://jsonplaceholder.typicode.com/users', { signal }) // <-- pass signal in fetch options
      .then(res => res.json())
      .then(json => {
        this.setState({
          isLoaded: true,
          data: json,
        })
      })
      // catch any rejected fetch promises (including aborted fetches!)
      .catch(console.error);
  }

  componentWillUnmount(){
    this.isLoaded=false;
    this.controller.abort(); // <-- abort any in-flight fetch requests
  }
...
```

[image: Edit cancel fetch request on unmount]

***NOTE:*** `fetch` normally only returns rejected Promises for network errors, valis HTML error responses will return in resolved Promises. As noted in comment, aborted fetches will also return a rejection.

Comment: Thank you, that took care of the error.  However, it also generated a new one.  My understanding is that aborting a fetch using the abort controller will automatically generate an error, is that what I am getting?  The error is: "Uncaught error: The error you provided does not contain a stack trace."  There is a second error: "Uncaught (in promise) DOMException: The user aborted a request."  This one I understand.

Comment: @Ron When `abort()` is called, the `fetch` promise rejects with a `DOMException` named `AbortError`. This can be caught in the `fetch` promise chain. I updated answer and provided codesandbox. FYI, error reporting can be a little flaky in codesandbox since it runs in an iframe.

Answer (score 0):

According to official React docs, life cycle method **componentWillUnmount** should be used for a set of scenarios, basically to do any kind of cleanup.

What does cleanup mean, it is nothing but canceling any event listeners you may have added for any element rendered by the current component, or maybe you initialized a subscription in your **componentDidMount** method. Or a network call that you may have initialized.

In a nutshell, remove, cancel, or clean any kind of service which was started by this component during its lifetime so far.

What you should never do in a **componentWillUnmount** method is to set the local state. As this setState will trigger a render, and this render will never be actioned, Why ?

Because once a component is unmounted/destroyed. It would have no effect of that setState called in **componentWillUnmount**.
Moreover this setState that you are trying to call from **componentWillUnmount** is what React refers to as the memory leaks.

For more in depth information, I would suggest reading the official doc [here](https://reactjs.org/docs/react-component.html#componentwillunmount)